# AWS AutoScaling CoolDown components

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, autoscaling

In AWS, the autoscaling group has a default cool down setting.
Also a policy can be defined to be triggered by an alarm and also have a cool down period for its scaling activity.

Is the actual cool down after a scaling the sum of these two cool down periods or the Maximum out of these two?

If ASG defaults to 60 seconds
And a Scale Out Policy is set to be 90 seconds

How much cool down period will be given after the Scaling out action is taken.

Answer (score 4):

The default cool down applies if you do not define cool down value in your scale out/in policy.
If you define a cool down in your policy, this cool down value applies for this policy (no sum, no max or anything).

So, regarding your question, you'll have a 90s cool down.

More details on official documentation : [Scaling Cooldowns for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html)

Answer (score 1):

> A scaling-specific cooldown period overrides the default cooldown period.

Source: [Scaling specific cooldowns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html#cooldowns-scaling-specific)